# Mapping using ggmap

Tags: r, google-maps, openstreetmap

I am currently learning how to use ggmaps and have found a wrapper called qmap

I am attempting to map crime in Houston using the code [below](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf)

```
# Give you a bubble map
theme_set(theme_bw(16))
HoustonMap <- qmap("houston", zoom = 14, color = "bw", legend = "topleft", source = "osm")
```

I have specified my source as OSM but am getting the below error because it looks like I'm trying to connect to google maps (this API is blocked in workso i want to test other APIs)

***Error in download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=houston&zoom=14&size=640x640&maptype=terrain&sensor=false'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = tmp, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'***

Can anyone see why?

Comment: This line from the ggmap CRAN manual also failed. `qmap(location = "baylor university", zoom = 14, source = "osm")`. I wonder if something is going on with osm.

Comment: If i input the link in the error message into a web browser, should it return something as it looks like its google returning the 404 message (this works at home on my laptop without any problems). However, i have tried all the sources now and it seems to always go to google maps except in the case of cloudmade

Comment: I think it is worth sending an email to David Kahle who is the author of the package. He may have some ideas of what is going on.

Comment: After talking with Mr Kahle, it seems that the proxy in my office is actually blocked by google maps. I have gotten IT to switch us to a different proxy and it seems to work now off of google maps

Comment: Thanks for the message. I am glad to hear that you solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

[What's going on with get_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965213/whats-going-on-with-get-map) answers this question.

You should provide lat/lon coordinates instead of `"houston"` to call OpenStreetMap api instead of google.